# Mysql2 query is not working on Heroku

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, activerecord

I have a mysql query which does not work with postgresql :-

```
@events = Event.all_with_distance([current_user.geo_lat, current_user.geo_lng]).where("start > ?", Time.zone.now).order("distance").order("start DESC").where("title like ?", "%#{params[:q]}%")

def self.all_with_distance(origin)
    distance_sql = sql_for_distance(origin)
    select("#{table_name}.*, #{distance_sql} AS distance").select("`locations`.`geo_lat`, `locations`.`geo_lng`, `locations`.`name` as location_name").joins(:location).where("#{distance_sql} < 50")
  end
```

This is the error which I get :-

```
PG::Error: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: ...SIN(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * SIN(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`...
```

Generated Query :-

```
SELECT events.*, (ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * SIN(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) + COS(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lng`) - RADIANS(80.9466832)) ) * 6378.135)  AS distance, `locations`.`geo_lat`, `locations`.`geo_lng`, `locations`.`name` as location_name FROM "events" INNER JOIN "locations" ON "locations"."id" = "events"."location_id" WHERE ((ACOS( SIN(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * SIN(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) + COS(RADIANS(26.8465108)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lat`)) * COS(RADIANS(`locations`.`geo_lng`) - RADIANS(80.9466832)) ) * 6378.135)  < 50) AND (start > '2012-09-21 06:40:18.964016') AND (title like '%%') ORDER BY distance, start DESC
```

Comment: Couldn't you use plain ActiveRecord query methods?

Comment: I wouldn't know without looking at either your schema.rb and/or your models.

Comment: please provide your generated query

Comment: @Salil updated the question with generated query and the exact line on which I am getting the error

Comment: using \"\" instead of '' does not help much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes Back Ticks were MySql-ism

after removing '' with "" it worked fine.

Here is the query after the change :-

```
select("#{table_name}.*, #{distance_sql} AS distance").select('"locations"."geo_lat", "locations"."geo_lng", "locations"."name" as location_name').joins(:location).where("#{distance_sql} < 50")
```